# What sites/publications are good for staying current on security and malware trends?

Tags: security, website, malware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Security Resources](https://serverfault.com/questions/34523/security-resources)

In my ever expanding quest for knowledge, I'm at the point where I feel like I need to be more up to date with the current security trends, as well as malware and such that are in the wild.  I'd like to be able to say, "I've heard of that and the fix is...." versus, "Oh, yeah, I had that eat up half my network before I contained it...."  What sites and publications are good for keeping up with these things?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Security Resources](http://serverfault.com/questions/34523/security-resources)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/26213/keeping-up-with-security as well.. Not sure of these cover malware though.

Comment: @Kyle I just looked at the links you listed.  I didn't see them because I searched for malware.  They are good for security reads, but I'm also interested on something highly focused on malware.  Current trojans in the field, how to identify systems compromised with malware and fix them, etc.

Comment: Actually found a bit of what I was looking for with [Security Resources](http://serverfault.com/questions/34523/security-resources).  Voted to close.

Answer (score 2):

[BUGTRAQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugtraq).

Subscribing to the vendor announce and security mailing lists for the software you use is advised too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be aware of new vulnerabilties found: [SecurityFocus](http://www.securityfocus.com/rss/vulnerabilities.xml)

Information about current website hacking: [Sucuri Security](http://feeds.feedburner.com/SucuriSecurity)

Web security: [Zscaler Research blog](http://feeds2.feedburner.com/zscaler/research)

Answer (score 1):

I personally like [darkreading.com](http://www.darkreading.com)